# How to delete and replace field separator from column using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have CSV file like this:

```
name_var;type_var;
id;string;
dt_depot;string;
num_artc;string
```

I want to delete the first's `;` and replace the last ones by `,`  so the output would look like:

```
name_var type_var,
id string,
dt_depot string,
num_artc string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` something like can do the work:

```
awk -F\; '{print $1" "$2","}'
```

If you do not like the last comma it can be rewrited like this:

```
 awk -F\; '{ if (NF != 2) print $1" "$2","; else  print $1" "$2;}'
```

Comment: Yes, but the `" "` between `$1` and `$2` can be replaced by a comma (space is the default output field delimiter): `print $1, $2 ","`.  This (and your code) would however place a comma on _each_ line.

Comment: @Kusalananda, now should look better :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply with `sed` substitution:

```
$ sed 's/;$/,/; s/;/ /g' file
name_var type_var,
id string,
dt_depot string,
num_artc string
```

---

As for `awk` solution, if input file is supposed to contain only 2 filled columns - you may go with the following `awk` expression:

```
$ awk -F";" '{ if (NF==3) $2=$2","; print $1,$2 }' file
name_var type_var,
id string,
dt_depot string,
num_artc string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F';' '{sub(/;$/,","); $1=$1} 1' file
name_var type_var,
id string,
dt_depot string,
num_artc string
```

The script changes every `;` at the end of a line to `,` then converts every remaining `;` to `,` by assigning a value to a field which causes all input field separators (`;` as set by `-F';'`) to be changed to the output field separator (a blank by default). It then prints the current line by specifying a true condition (1) which invokes the default action (`print $0`).

Comment: Thank you for yout answer ! can you just comment the code please because i'm beginner  in Shell, thanx !

Answer (score 0):

With this command:

```
awk '{sub(/;$/,",")sub(/;/," ")}1' file
```

You get this output:

```
name_var type_var,
id string,
dt_depot string,
num_artc string
```